# How to pass parameters in React from Function to class

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie to reactjs and I would like to ask if it is possible to achieve this.

I have two files, I would like to pass the locationProps from Daily.js to myData.js

Heres my code:

**myData.js**

```
class myData {
  constructor() {
    this.updateData();
  }

  getTimes(date = null) {
    date = date === null ? moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY') : date;
    var data = this.getData();
    return data ? data[date] : [];
  }


  getSpeadsheetUrl() {
    return config.SpeadsheetUrl[locationProps]; // -----> How to pass this locationProps ? 
  }
```

---

**Daily.js**

```
function Daily({ locationProps = 1, root }) {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const localization = useCallback(() => {
    if (root && cookies.get("location") !== undefined) {
      return cookies.get("location");
    }
    return locationProps;
  }, [locationProps, root]);


const getTimes=() =>{
  var _data = new myData();
  return _data.getTimes();
}
```

```
function App() {
  return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          {locations.map(location => (
            <Route
              key={location}
              exact
              path={`/${slugify(location, {
                replacement: "-",
                remove: null,
                lower: true
              })}`}
              render={() => (
                <Daily locationProps={locations.indexOf(location)} />

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi, can you share more complete code? How is `Daily` being rendered? What is the relationship between `Daily` and `myData`?

Comment: here is the relation in daily.js ```const getTimes=() =>{
  var _data = new myData();
  return _data.getTimes();
}```

Comment: Oh, some prop from `Daily` to a function, do you mean something like `_data.getSpreadsheetUrl(locationProps);`?

Comment: yes for detail i have liste of city and list of Url from google speadsheet and defaut city locationprop=1 get url 1 and if user change city the locationprops change to index of city

Comment: Now just I want class myData acces to this variable from function Daily if it possible thank you

Comment: Where in `Daily` are you trying to call `getSpreadsheetUrl`? What do you do with the return value?

Comment: if I write like this ```getSpeadsheetUrl() {
    return config.SpeadsheetUrl[1]; 
  }``` i get url from city number one but I want the url change when user change location

Comment: No in Daily I call the class MyData here ```const getTimes=() =>{
  var _data = new myData();
  return _data.getTimes();
}``` and I want the CLass MyData get the variable locationprops in getSpeadsheetUrl()

Comment: You need to pass `locationProps` to that function then. How else would `myData` know when it changes, let alone that it even exists?

Comment: It's impossible to pass Locationprops ?

Comment: It's completely possible to pass arguments to functions. Answered below with a suggested solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `getSpreadshhetUrl` to take the `locationProps` as a parameter so they can be passed:

```
getSpeadsheetUrl(locationProps) {
  return config.SpeadsheetUrl[locationProps];
}
```

Then within `Daily` on the instantiated `_data` instance you can invoke the function with the current `locationProps`

```
_data.getSpreadSheetUrl(locationProps);
```

You likely only want to invoke this function when `locationProps` change, so you can place it in an effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  _data.getSpreadSheetUrl(locationProps);
}, [locationProps]);
```

Now the question is what and where is `_data`? I recommend storing it in a ref so it's accessible from the entire functional component:

```
function Daily({ locationProps = 1, root }) {
  const _data = useRef(new myData());

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    _data.current.getSpreadSheetUrl(locationProps);
  }, [locationProps]);

  ...

  const getTime = () => _data.current.getTimes();

  ...
}
```

*Auxiliary Suggestion*

You can use the `array.map` index parameter and omit the index search when setting the `locationProps` value.

```
locations.map((location, index) => (
  <Route
    key={location}
    exact
    path={`/${slugify(location, {
      replacement: "-",
      remove: null,
      lower: true
    })}`}
    render={() => (
      <Daily locationProps={index} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a reactjs question. It's just a normal JS question that happens to involve react.

myData is a class, so in order to pass data into it, you need to make that data be arguments in it's constructor, which you can then call with `new myData(locationProps)`

Hope this helps!

```
class myData {
  constructor(locationProps) {
    this.locationProps = locationProps;
    this.updateData();
  }

  getTimes(date = null) {
    date = date === null ? moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY') : date;
    var data = this.getData();
    return data ? data[date] : [];
  }

  getSpeadsheetUrl() {
    return config.SpeadsheetUrl[this.locationProps]; // -----> How to pass this locationProps ?
  }
}


function Daily({ locationProps = 1, root }) {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const localization = useCallback(() => {
    if (root && cookies.get('location') !== undefined) {
      return cookies.get('location');
    }
    return locationProps;
  }, [locationProps, root]);

  const getTimes = () => {
    var _data = new myData(locationProps);
    return _data.getTimes();
  };
}
```

Comment: thank you but I get Error 'locationProps' is not defined  no-undef